# iOS simulator takes over 1 hour to run an app

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator

My Xcode and iOS simulator suddenly came to take too long time to run an app.
The build itself can complete within 15 mins even if full-build, but after that, the Xcode's message box shows "Waiting for iPhone X to start" (of course, "iPhone X" is an example). Even after the boot of a simulator, the app installation is not started for a long time.

Before the problem, the app installation was started once a build finished and a simulator booted.

I doubted my code, so I also tried with another very simple code, but the same problem remains.

Do you have any insights to help me?

Xcode and iOS simulator: 10.1 / 
Mac: MacBook 2017, CPU 1.4GHz i7, Memory 16GB, macOS Mojave 10.14.4

Comment: Update Xcode to 10.2?

Comment: Thanks, yes it's an option for me, but I don't try it yet not to make things more complicated. I will try it in case of no other choices.

Comment: I tried the update to Xcode 10.2.1, and the problem is resolved... I’m completely not sure the reason, but the old Xcode might have some problems during the transition period to the next version... Thank you all for your advices!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the update to Xcode 10.2.1, and the problem is resolved... I’m completely not sure the reason, but the old Xcode might have some problems during the transition period to the next version... Thank you all for your advices!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your memory is saturated, or your stockage is saturated. Contact Apple if your problem is still here. You can discuss with them here : https://www.apple.com/shop/help

Comment: Thanks, but CPU usage is around 20-30%, Memory usage 12 out of 16GB.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset your simulator and all its settings.

Open the simulator and click on the menu bar option **Hardware** -> **Erase All Content and Settings…**

[image]